# TreeMap with List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections, spring-data

'''

```
@Override
    public TreeMap<String, List<String>> getCityWithPincode() {
        List<User> listOfUser = findAllUser();

        TreeMap<String, List<String>> tm = new TreeMap<>();

        for(User user : listOfUser) {
            
            if(tm.isEmpty()) {
                tm.put(user.getCity(), Arrays.asList(user.getPincode()));
            }
            else {
                
                if(tm.containsKey(user.getCity())) {
                    List<String> list = tm.get(user.getCity());
                    
                    list.add(user.getPincode());
                    
                    tm.put(user.getCity(), list);
                }
                else {
                    tm.put(user.getCity(), Arrays.asList(user.getPincode()));
                }
                
            }
            
        }

        return tm;
    }
```

'''

Im trying collect city with there city pincode and in one city have somany pincode right so i have created treemap for collecting this details and key is a city and value is a list of pincode but this not working...

Error is :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-11-27T06:37:21.712+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)\r\n\tat com.admin.panel.service.UserServiceImpl.getCityWithPincode(UserServiceImpl.java:182)\r\n\tat com.admin.panel.controller.UserController.getCityWithPincode(UserController.java:167)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\n",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/user/citywithpincode/cal"
}
```

Comment: Post the proper error and not from the context of running your server. How we do know which line is the problem?

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your title.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the stack trace, the `add()` method on `AbstractList` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

You cannot add a new element into a list returned by `Arrays.asList()`, because it's backed by an array wrapped around the elements provided as arguments while calling `asList()` and for that reason doesn't support structural modifications.

Either create an empty list of your choice and add to it, or wrap the `Arrays.asList` call with a mutable list, say an `ArrayList`

```
tm.put(user.getCity(), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user.getPincode())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `new ArrayList<>()` instead of `Arrays.asList()`.
You cannot add elements to the list returned by `Arrays.asList()`.

And you can simplify the code by using `Map.computeIfAbsent()`.

```
public TreeMap<String, List<String>> getCityWithPincode() {
    List<User> listOfUser = findAllUser();

    TreeMap<String, List<String>> tm = new TreeMap<>();

    for(User user : listOfUser) {
        tm.computeIfAbsent(user.getCity(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(user.getPincode());
    }
    return tm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Stream API:

- stream the list of users
- Use [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) with `Function<User, String>` as the key extractor, `Supplier<Map>` as the map factory and `Collectors.mapping` as the downstream collector:

  - get the user's city for a key `User::getCity`
  - `TreeMap::new` - create instance of the sorted map
  - build list of pincode with the help of mapping users to their pincodes and storing the list: `Collectors.mapping(User::getPinCode, Collectors.toList())`

```java
@Override
public TreeMap<String, List<String>> getCityWithPincode() {
    return findAllUser()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                User::getCity,   // key - city name
                TreeMap::new,    // create TreeMap instance
                Collectors.mapping(
                    User::getPinCode, Collectors.toList()
                )               // List<String> pin codes
            ));
}
```